Migrate from wordpress options to custom table
I created a WordPress plugin. I created a few settings and saved them in an option using add_option(). Now, I have 10,000+ data in the wp_options table.
I need to migrate that data from wp_options to the custom table, as it is crucial for the functionality of my WordPress plugin.
I have tried to run a cron job, but the problem is that it was our clients' plugin, and they are using the feature. The new plugin I have created is not working on wp_options; it was working on the custom table.
How do I migrate from wp_options to a custom table?
